# unicorn socket refuse connect after centos user logout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn

i ran into a very strange problem. i have a nginx and configed fine to use a rails unicorn server.
i use 'unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -E producttion -D'  to start my unicorn server.
everything worked fine unless i logout my ssh sesstion.

after i logout my ssh session, the rails app will down.

and when i check the nginx log,it says that the socket.pid refused to connect.
and i find the unicorn's socket file just sit there and the unicorn's process are all alive.

the only solution is to kill the unicorn process and restart again.

i am so confused, anyone could help me? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try running the process in the background using `nohup unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -D`

This may help you however it's been a while since I had to startup my webserver through SSH without an init.d script or similar. You may get better help on SuperUser though since they deal more with systems stuff.

Comment: thanks Devin, i tried this but it doesn't work either, and i think it is not because of this, cause when later I loged in , i found the process works fine, but only got those error messages.

Comment: Hmm, so does the unicorn process stop working right as the user logs out?

Comment: yes, it is strange, i still can use 'ps -aux | grep uni' to see it alive, but the nginx say the unicorn.socket can not be connected.